# WPF: Show new window using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to launch a new window in WPF using XAML? Or does it have to be done from code behind?

Comment: Mark siz as the answer, you aren't going to get the answer you're waiting for because his is right.

Comment: Sorry about that, went away and forgot to come back! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can only be done from code-behind because window is a root-level element.